# Determining whether the set of lines in $\Bbb R^2$ with at least two points whose coordinates are rational is a countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ denote the subset $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ of $\Bbb R^2$ and $U$ denote the set of all lines in $\Bbb R^2$ that intersect with $A$ in at least two points.

Now I know $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is countable. How does that help to determine whether $U$ is countable or not? Is $U = (\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q)\times(\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q)$?

Comment: There is a surjection from $(Q\times Q)\times (Q\times Q)$ onto $U$, given by taking the line between the two points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The slopes of these lines are rational. The map $L \to (x,y,m)$ where $(x,y)$ is some fixed  point of $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ in $L$ and $m$ is the slope of $L$ gives a one-to-one map of $U$ into $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Oh i get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given any two points a UNIQUE line passes through them.